# Downloading pdf files

Tags: web-crawlers

I have very basic programming skills or other computer skills.
I wanted to download whole web content including pdf text files from a website, by going through each pdf and downloading them individually is taking my time. what is this webcrawler and can i use it to download all of this files? again very limited or no knowledge about these. Can you let me know how to proceed? Will very much appreciate

Comment: does httrack download pdf and other links from a website?

Answer (score 1):

The only software I know to do this is [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/page/1/en/index.html).

Comment: Thank you!! will it download pdf files and web content? i am in urgent need to download all these files, i hope it works

Comment: Yes, it gets all the website.

Comment: I dont want pdf files as links, i want it as files, is that possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible.